# localtime() function shows two equals date

Tags: c

Why when i try to show 2 dates with different arguments, that i put into localtime() function,  console show 2 equal dates?

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main() {
    time_t time1, time2;
    struct tm *timeinfo1, *timeinfo2;
    char *time1str, *time2str;

    time1 = 3600;
    time2 = 3720;
    timeinfo1 = localtime(&time1);
    timeinfo2 = localtime(&time2);

    time1str = asctime(timeinfo1);
    time2str = asctime(timeinfo2);
    puts(time1str);
    puts(time2str);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data wouldn't persist between two calls to `localtime` or `asctime`. You have to copy data somewhere. Here is corrected example (still have little issue with strncpy):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    time_t time1, time2;
    struct tm timeinfo1, timeinfo2, *ti;
    char time1str[256], time2str[256], *tstr;

    time1 = 3600;
    time2 = 3720;
    ti = localtime(&time1);
    memcpy(&timeinfo1, ti, sizeof(*ti));
    ti = localtime(&time2);
    memcpy(&timeinfo2, ti, sizeof(*ti));

    tstr = asctime(&timeinfo1);
    strncpy(time1str, tstr, sizeof(time1str) - 1);
    tstr = asctime(&timeinfo2);
    strncpy(time2str, tstr, sizeof(time1str) - 1);

    puts(time1str);
    puts(time2str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just initialise the character arrays properly like so `char time1str[256] = {0}, time2str[256] = {0}` and your use of `strncpy()` is safe.

Comment: @alk well, last byte would be enough. It just seems not so effective - both initializing full array and fact that strncpy will fill it with zeroes every time. Not too important, just personally don't like it's behaviour. It's much better when `strlcpy` is available, but alas.

Comment: You are right. However I go for writing save code in the 1st place (which includes initialising **all** variables) and when going for optimisation (if ever) one could tweak around here.

Answer (score 4):

From the [doc of localtime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/) :

> The returned value points to an internal object whose validity or value may be altered by any subsequent call to gmtime or localtime.

`localtime()` returns twice the same pointer : You are working twice on the same data.

Test:

```
printf("%p\n", localtime(&time1));
printf("%p\n", localtime(&time2));
```

Output :

```
0x7f7d9d2eee80
0x7f7d9d2eee80
```

Answer (score 2):

`localtime()` and `asctime()` each return a pointer to an internal buffer. This buffer is overwritten every time `localtime()` or `asctime()` is called, so in the OP's code the result of the first call is replaced by the result of the second call.

To have the different times printed just rearrange the order of the calls like so:

```
timeinfo1 = localtime(&time1);
time1str = asctime(timeinfo1);
puts(time1str);

timeinfo2 = localtime(&time2);
time2str = asctime(timeinfo2);
puts(time2str);
```

Alternativly if using a POSIX compliant system use `localtime_r()` and `asctime_r()` which use a buffer provided by the caller:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(void) 
{
  time_t time1 = 3600;
  time_t time2 = 3720;

  struct tm timeinfo1 = {0};      
  struct tm timeinfo2 = {0};

  char time1str[32] = "";
  char time2str[32] = "";

  localtime_r(&time1, &timeinfo1);
  localtime_r(&time2, &timeinfo2);

  asctime_r(&timeinfo1, timestr1);
  asctime_r(&timeinfo2, timestr2);

  puts(time1str);
  puts(time2str);

  getch();

  return 0;
}
```

*Please note the different declaration of the vàriables `timeinfo?` and `time?str`.*

Answer (score 0):

> Why ... console show 2 equal dates?

`localtime()` and `gmtime()` return a pointer to a shared `struct tm` memory location.

Like [@keltar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19422711/2410359) good answer, to retain `struct tm` information, code should copy that `struct tm` before a subsequent `localtime(), gmtime()` call.

Instead of `mempcy()` a simple assignment `=` will do.

```
// struct tm *timeinfo1, *timeinfo2;  // Not pointers
struct tm timeinfo1, timeinfo2;       // ... but structures. 

time1 = 3600;
time2 = 3720;
// timeinfo1 = localtime(&time1);  // Rather than copy the pointer
// timeinfo2 = localtime(&time2);
//          v--------------------- // Notice the *
timeinfo1 = *localtime(&time1);    // Copy the structure
timeinfo2 = *localtime(&time2);
```